# How to upload file using a form without an entity class

Tags: php, symfony

I've tried to upload file using a form without an entity class. No luck so far.

```
  // Controller
  public function uploadAction() {
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('images', 'file') // If I remove this line data is submitted correctly
            ->add('dir', 'text')
            ->getForm();

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
      $request = $this->getRequest();
      $form->bindRequest($request);

      $data = $form->getData();
      var_dump($data);
    }   
    else
      return $this->render('OverseerMainBundle:Default:form.html.twig', array(
          'form' => $form->createView(),
      )); 
  }

// form.html.twig
{% block body %}
<form action="{{ path('OverseerMainBundle_upload') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    {{ form_widget(form) }}

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

So far var_dump echoes:

```
array(2) { ["images"]=> NULL ["dir"]=> NULL }
```

However if I remove line `->add('images', 'file')` everything is ok:

```
array(1) { ["dir"]=> string(4) "test" }
```

P.S. I've checked html code of form and attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is presented. So it's not an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked that the file doesn't exceed the server maximum file size limit?  The default is 2MB.  I haven't used Symfony 2.0 yet so I am not sure of that.

Comment: LOL, no worries man we all do it at one point or another.  Have some more coffee.

Answer (score 6):

Also I hope this would help others:

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
        $file = $form->get('file')->getData();
        $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $dir = __DIR__.'/../../../../web/uploads';

        $file->move($dir, $name) ;
    }
```

Comment: Does anyone know why $form->get('file')->getData() is not working in Symfony 2.7.40 ? It returns null.

Comment: Found the answer, it's v2.7.38 that introduced a BC by fixing a security bug https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/24993

Comment: I have stopped using 2.7 and bellow. I have jumped from 2.3 to 2.8 and I am currently preparing for 3.4.